# Python - Writing to a New Line

Tags: python, string, file

I have looked at the many other threads on this topic, but I cannot seem to find the right code that appends the new line at the end of the file.

Here is my code :

```
Name=input('What is your name:')
Date=input('What is the date:')
Score=input('What was your high score:')

myFile=open('Scores.txt','a')
myFile.write("{},{},{}"+"\n".format(Name, Date, Score))
myFile.close()
```

However, the only thing that seems to output in the Score.txt file is `{},{},{}`.
My intended output is that each time I run this program, it will output the new data onto a new line, without overwriting the line above it.

Comment: What is your intended output?

Comment: My intended output is that so each time I am too run this program, it will output the new data onto a new line, without overwriting the line above it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"{},{},{}"+"\n".format(Name, Date, Score)`

You are calling the `format` method on string `"\n"`.

Try `"{},{},{}\n".format(Name, Date, Score)`

Answer (score 2):

When you do:

```
"{},{},{}"+"\n".format(Name, Date, Score)
```

Python interprets it as:

```
"{},{},{}"+("\n".format(Name, Date, Score))
```

because the method invocation  `.format(...)` [has a tighter binding](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) than the `+` operator.  Meaning, it applies to just the string `"\n"` and not the combined string `"{},{},{}"+"\n"`.

Moreover, calling the `str.format` method on the string `"\n"` is effectively a no-op:

```
>>> "\n".format(1, 2, 3)
'\n'
>>>
```

So, the string that is written to the file is just `"{},{},{}"+"\n"` or `"{},{},{}\n"`.

---

To fix the problem, simply include the newline in the format string:

```
myFile.write("{},{},{}\n".format(Name, Date, Score))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are currently formatting the **\n**

to format the whole string you need to tell that's the **\n** is a part of your string.

```
myFile.write(str("{},{},{}"+"\n").format(Name, Date, Score))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's formatting the `\n` (new line) string and then adding the braces.  Try this.

```
myFile.write( ("{},{},{}"+"\n").format(Name, Date, Score) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use brackets:

```
myFile.write(("{},{},{}"+"\n").format(Name, Date, Score))
```

Or, maybe better:

```
myFile.write(("{},{},{}\n").format(Name, Date, Score))
```

Then the `.format` will be applied to the whole string.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
Name=input('What is your name:')
Date=input('What is the date:')
Score=input('What was your high score:')

myFile=open('Scores.txt','a')
myFile.write("{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n".format(Name, Date, Score))
myFile.close()
```

Take a look at this documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples to see format examples.

Also you forget to use "\n" on each value.

Regards,